# Pitest is failing and not generating mutation coverage

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, pitest

I'm trying to run Pitest in my project, but keep receiving this error:

`Failed to execute goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.14.2:mutationCoverage (default-cli) on project image-finder: Execution default-cli of goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.14.2:mutationCoverage failed: No mutations found. This probably means there is an issue with either the supplied classpath or filters.`

I'm trying to run Pitest from the command line using: `mvn clean org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage`

Fortunately I'm using IntelliJ and there is an IntelliJ Pitest plugin available, and when I run it, it does work. However, I want it to also work from the command line.

I've tried:

- Setting targetClasses and targetTests

  - Using `<param>`, `<targetTest>`, `<targetClass>` for each to specify the target classes and test classes
  - Specified classes as such: `com.package.examples.*` for non-test classes
  - Specified test classes as both: `com.package.examples.*Test` and `com.package.examples.*`
- Not setting targetClasses and targetTests
- Updating Maven surefire plugin to the latest version
- Not setting any configurations for Pitest in my `pom.xml`

I'm using JUnit 5 and have included the necessary dependency in the Pitest plugin. I'm not sure why I keep receiving this error.

My pom file currently:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.kyleryxn</groupId>
    <artifactId>image-finder</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>image-finder</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>17</jdk.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>${jdk.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>${jdk.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <spring.version>6.0.10</spring.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <mockito.version>5.4.0</mockito.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Core libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database libraries -->


        <!-- Servlet libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web framework libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring6</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
            <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>image-finder</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.json</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <!-- Update default Maven plugin versions -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
                <version>1.14.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: First you are mixing junit jupiter and junit 4 indirectly via `pl.pragmatists` ... furthermore you have not defined the `junit-jupiter-engine` and the question is also are all your tests executed correctly during a usual `mvn clean test`? And very important via `mvn clean org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage` can not work because mutation tests needs executed tests which mean you have to use `mvn clean test org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage`...

Comment: I am using JUnit 5, and the dependency I'm using consists of all the JUnit 5  dependencies (hence the plugin for my Pitest plugin), so I do not need to define the engine. But nevertheless, I figured out the issue and you're right, it has something to do with the Pitest configuration and tests